# OSX: Momentary appearance of a .dmg modal, when opening an image

Tags: macos, disk-image

I had a situation that struck me as odd.

- I opened an image which I had downloaded via browser save-as.
- After the finder/OS initiated the file-open,
- a modal dialog momentarily flashed, typical to when a .dmg file is being opened.
- This went away without interaction, and the file opened in Preview.

What could have caused this?

Are there known viruses that hijack part of the process?

---

It may be relevant: I opened the file via Firefox Nightly, using the download manager to reveal-on-disk